# Did Tito back the Bulgarian anti Communist Goryani resistance movement?

Tags: cold-war, yugoslavia, bulgaria

I was doing Wikipedia based (mixed quality source) research on the Goryani anti communist resistance movement in Bulgaria and found the following interesting statement:

“During the same period, some 15 Goryani parachuted into the Kazanlak and Ihtiman areas from training camps in Yugoslavia and France.”

[Wikipedia: Goryani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goryani)

It is very unlikely that Tito would have not have known about these training camps inside his country. I would presume that he allowed them to be there. The question is why. Why would he permit  a Bulgarian anti-Communist   movement to seek sanctuary within his own country?

What is it simply a deal between the two forces, where they both shared a common enemy with the Kremlin backed Soviet forces ruling Bulgaria?

Or did Tito back some faction of the Bulgarian anti-communist resistance movement that was willing to support his ambitions for a pan Balkan Confederation (and found Tito’s version of communism more ‘tolerable’). This question is based on the following Wikipedia data:

“Tito planned to absorb Albania and Greece in cooperation with Bulgaria, thereby setting up a powerful Eastern Europe bloc outside Moscow's control. Stalin could not tolerate that...”

[Wikipedia: Tito Stalin Split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tito%E2%80%93Stalin_Split)

I find it odd that Tito would back such a hard-core anti-Communist rebel movement. The reference to this rebel movement having training camps  in France is also fascinating. France was a member of NATO at the time.  If this information is valid, then it implies that there was at least one case where NATO and Yugoslavia worked together to threaten Soviet interests in eastern Europe.

I posted this question to seek more details on these topics as well as to spark further research amongst others who may find this interesting.

Comment: The ennemy of my ennemy is my friend. At least for a while. Rebellions and Revolutions are hardly started by moderates.

Answer (score 2):

> **The question is why. Why would Tito permit a Bulgarian anti-Communist** 
>   **movement to seek sanctuary within his own country?**

Because communist Tito in the 1950's wasn't aligned with the Soviet Union. By 1951 he was receiving [US economic and military aid](http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/united-states-gives-military-and-economic-aid-to-communist-yugoslavia). By 1953 he was [tacitly aligned with NATO(1953)](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Josip-Broz-Tito).  Threat of imminent Soviet invasion moved him from proSoviet to nonaligned, and that manifested itself as being pro western from time to time.

> I find it odd that Tito would back such a hard-core anti-Communist
>   rebel movement. The reference to this rebel movement having training
>   camps in France is also fascinating. France was a member of NATO at
>   the time. If this information is valid, then it implies that there was
>   at least one case where NATO and Yugoslavia worked together to
>   threaten Soviet interests in eastern Europe.

This example of the communist Marshal Tito's aid to NATO to the detriment of the Soviet Union was not unique.  And the example you site wasn't the most important aid Marshal Tito performed for NATO in that period.   In 1951 Tito closed Yugoslavia's boarders to the Soviet backed guerrillas operating in Greece and the post WWII communist revolution in Greece Collapsed.

**A Little background**

Tito and Stalin had split in 1948.  In 1948 when it became clear Stalin wasn't backing Marshal Tito's plans to take over Greece, Albania, and Bulgaria; and equally clear to Stalin Tito would not allow Yugoslavia to become a puppet state; Yugoslavia fell outside of the Soviet sphere of influence.  Yugoslavia's brand of communism, with its independence from the Soviet line, was called Titoism by Moscow and considered treasonous.  Party purges against suspected "Titotes" were conducted throughout Eastern Europe.  [In his memoirs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informbiro_period), Nikita Khrushchev asserted that he was "absolutely sure that if the Soviet Union bordered Yugoslavia, Stalin would have intervened militarily."  Tito expected Stalin to invade and started to take steps.  This period is called [informbiro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informbiro_period) and it spanned seven years of 1948 to 1955.

The United States aware of the split started courting Tito:

- [In 1949 The United States supported Yugoslavia's bit for a seat on
  the United Nations Security Council.](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=MT19491020.2.20)
- Tito now [reconsidering pro USSR rebels in Greece](https://dangerouscitizens.columbia.edu/1946-1949/august-29-1949/1/index.html) closes his boarders to those rebels, they collapse, and gives NATO a big win.
- [By 1951 Yugoslavia was
  receiving US military and economic aid](http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/united-states-gives-military-and-economic-aid-to-communist-yugoslavia)

And Tito started poking the Bear.

> Every week brings new reports of [Yugoslav-provoked incidents](https://www.marxists.org/history/international/comintern/1951/trotsky-tito/ch04.htm) on 
>   the Bulgarian, Rumanian and Hungarian frontiers, where large numbers of
>   Titoite troops are concentrated.
>
> Between 2 April and 30 April 1951 alone the Titoite armed forces
>   violated the Albanian frontier eight times.
>
> [Tito Yugoslavia](https://www.marxists.org/history/international/comintern/1951/trotsky-tito/ch04.htm) has become an integral and important part in the war
>   plans of Western reaction:
>
> 1) By building up with Western aid an inflated army and police force
>   directed against the Soviet Union and the People’s Democracies.
>
> 2) By transforming Yugoslavia into a Western military base.
>
> 3) By acting as the organiser and centre of an anti-Soviet and
>   anti-People’s Democracy ‘security bloc’ on the borders of Eastern
>   Europe.
>
> 4) By developing disruptive and espionage fifth-column work inside its
>   Eastern European neighbours’ territory.
>
> 5) By orienting its economy to the export to Western imperialism and
>   its puppets of strategic raw materials needed for aggressive war.

- By 1953 Military and Economic aid to Yugoslavia had lead to an [informal relationship](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Josip-Broz-Tito) with NATO, which included a mutual defense treaty via Greece and Turkey.
- This also included Tito being hosted in Britain for a state visit.

[image]

- I've heard Tito referred to as NATO's favorite communist; but he proved to be bit of a wild card.  The tacitly supported the Soviet intervention in Hungary in 1956,  and then he harshly criticized the same kind of intervention in Czechoslovakia in 1968.  While the United States often admired Tito for his independent stance, especially when it worked in their favor, he could sometimes be a bit too independent. During the 1950s and 1960s he encouraged and supported the nonalignment movement among Third World nations, a policy that concerned American officials who were intent on forcing those nations to choose sides in the East-West struggle. Relations between the United States and Yugoslavia warmed considerably after Tito’s denunciation of the Czech intervention, but cooled again when he sided with the Soviets during the Arab-Israeli conflict of 1973. Tito died in 1980.